# How to add validation to Dynamic RadioButton and TextBox in a WebForm with ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, dynamic, webforms

The problem is when we create dynamicly RadioButtonList of 4 Radiobutton and 1 textbox related with the radioButtonList in a web form, the number on elments is not limited,so we can one or more RadioButtonList and textbox in the panel. That's why we have to use:

```
foreach (RadioButtonList rdbList in pnl1.Controls.OfType<RadioButtonList>())
{
    string idrdbDynamicList = "rdbDynamicList" + (n + 1);

    if (rdbList.ID.Contains(idrdbDynamicList))
    {
        ...
```

And we have to make validation for each elelment in panel created dynamicly.
For exemple : if we have RDB0, RDB1, RDB2, RDB4 and textbox1

- if we clicked on RDB0 we must put value in textbox1 else add messag error
- if we clicked on RDB1 textbox1 will be disable else add messag error
- if we clicked on RDB2 we must put value in textbox1 else add messag error
- if we clicked on RDB3 textbox1 is empty and enable else add messag error

and after that we have to post this elements.

If somewone can help me how to make validation in this case ?

Comment: Do you want client-side or server side validation or both?  You should probably include more of your code/markup.

Comment: If they are always used in pairs, consider creating a control that contains both and put the validation code in the control.  Then just add one control dynamically.

Comment: You need to create your own `CustomValidator` for this.

Comment: Yes both of them, client and server side.